# AttributeError while trying to access method of another file

Tags: python

I have created two python file and trying to call a function from one file to another but facing below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/BizomWeb/venv/lib/customlibs/validator.py", line 3, in <module>
    class validator():
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/BizomWeb/venv/lib/customlibs/validator.py", line 9, in validator
    func()
  File "/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/BizomWeb/venv/lib/customlibs/validator.py", line 6, in func
    excelData=ExcelLib.read_Excel(excelPath="/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/BizomWeb/venv/resources/Excel/ddata.xls")
AttributeError: module 'ExcelLib' has no attribute 'read_Excel'
```

ExcelLib.py:

```
class ExcelLib():

    def read_Excel(self,excelPath):
        data = pd.read_excel(excelPath)
        data_dict = pd.DataFrame(data).to_dict()
        json_str = json.dumps(data_dict)
        resp = json.loads(json_str)
        return resp
```

validator.py

```
import ExcelLib

class validator():

    def func():
        excelData=ExcelLib.read_Excel(excelPath="/home/sadha/PycharmProjects/BizomWeb/venv/resources/Excel/ddata.xls")
        print(excelData)

    func()
```

Comment: Should be `from ExcelLib import ExcelLib` in validator.py

Comment: Thanks it worked :)..can you please elaborate what is the difference between import excellib and from ExcelLib

Comment: Posted answer below, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In validator.py, you are importing the `ExcelLib` *module* but in the `validator.func` method, you appear to be trying to access the `ExcelLib` *class*.  To access the ExcelLib *class* in validoator.py, slimply change your `import` statement to the following which will import the class from the module:

```
from ExcelLib import ExcelLib
```